# How to uninstall Cuda7.5 from ubuntu?

Tags: nvidia, deep-learning, caffe

I have a NVIDIA jetson TX1 board. I want to install caffe on that. Based on Caffe prerequisites I installed CUDA toolkit from `https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads`. Later I found that this board has its own installtion description. It needs 10GB space and I do not have it since I have given some to Caffe prerequisites installations. 
Now I need to remove this CUDA toolkit completely. 
I did not find a sure way till now. Can you please help me?

I am using ubunto 14.4.+ NVIDIA jetson TX1

Comment: which type of installation did you use, `.run` or `.deb` ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 12):

**If you installed CUDA 7.5 using the .run :**

From the [manual](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/7.5/Prod/docs/sidebar/CUDA_Installation_Guide_Linux.pdf):

> 4.6. Uninstallation
>
> To uninstall the CUDA Toolkit, run the uninstallation script provided in the bin directory of the toolkit. By
>   default, it is located in `/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin`:

`$ sudo /usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin/uninstall_cuda_7.5.pl`

> To uninstall the NVIDIA Driver, run nvidia-uninstall:

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/nvidia-uninstall
```

**If you installed CUDA 7.5 using the .deb package:**

```
$ sudo apt-get purge cuda-7.5
```

(I think the package name is cuda-7.5, if it does not work, try with `cuda-7-5` or just `cuda`)

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get --purge -y remove 'cuda*'
sudo apt-get --purge -y remove 'nvidia*'
sudo reboot
```

It removes any installed cuda and nvidia packages and then you can install any specific version that you like from:
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive.

Answer (score 1):

To add up on mhaghighat's answer.

You can do this.

```
sudo apt purge -y '*cuda*'
sudo apt purge -y '*cudnn*'
reboot
```

Since you only asked about removing cuda, I assume you dont need to reinstall nvidia, so no need to remove that. Beware purge is a powerful command, use it with caution.